# INSERT a number in a column based on other columns OLD INSERTs

Tags: postgresql, triggers, autofill

In PostgreSQL I have this table... (there is a primary key in the most left side "timestamp02" which is not shown in this image, please don't bother, its not important for the purpose of this question)

[image]

in the table above, all columns are entered via queries, except the "time_index" which I would like to be filled automatically via a trigger each time each row is filled.

This is the code to create the same table (without any value) so everyone could create it using the Postgre SQL query panel.

```
CREATE TABLE table_ebscb_spa_log02
(
  pcnum smallint,
  timestamp02 timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  fn_name character varying,
  "time" time without time zone,
  time_elapse character varying,
  time_type character varying,
  time_index real,
  CONSTRAINT table_ebscb_spa_log02_pkey PRIMARY KEY (timestamp02)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE table_ebscb_spa_log02
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

What I would like the trigger to do is:

INSERT a number in the "time_index" column based on the INSERTed values of the "fn_name" and "time_type" columns in each row.

If both ("fn_name" and "time_type") do a combination (eg. Check Mails - Start) that doesn't exist in any row before (above), then INSERT 1 in the "time_index" column,

Elif both ("fn_name" and "time_type") do a combination that does exist in some row before (above), then INSERT the number following the one before(above) in the "time_index" column.

(pls look at the example table image, this trigger will produce every red highlighted square on it)

I have watch many, PostgreSQL tutorial videos, read many manuals, including these

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

without any result.

I have tried so far this to create the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_ai_myTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
t_ix real;
n int;

BEGIN
IF NEW.time_type = 'Start' THEN
    SELECT t.time_index FROM table_ebscb_spa_log02 t WHERE t.fn_name = NEW.fn_name AND t.time_type = 'Start' ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC LIMIT 1 INTO t_ix;
      GET DIAGNOSTICS n = ROW_COUNT;
        IF (n = 0) THEN 
        t_ix = 1;
        ELSE 
        t_ix = t_ix + 1;
        END IF;
END IF;
NEW.time_index = t_ix;
return NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this to create the query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_ai_myTable
    AFTER INSERT ON table_ebscb_spa_log02
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_ai_myTable();
```

Then when I manually insert the values in the table, nothing change (no error message) time_index column just remain empty, what am I doing wrong???

Please some good PostgreSQL fellow programmer could give me a hand, I really have come to a death point in this task, I have any more ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes of course, I just don't know how to insert the values using a trigger, I heard STACKOVERFLOW was the right place to post my "question".

Comment: Well what do you have so far?

Comment: Start from here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtrigger.html Then try to create the triger yourself. Come back if you will have any problem or will not understand something and ask specific question.

Comment: Has been 3 days since I saw all examples in Postgre page, with no clue of how I could achieve mine, any hint? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/trigger-example.html

Comment: @Natysiu16 that explains how to create a trigger in C, you likely want to use PL/pgSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: sorry, wrong link, I meant this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-trigger.html  what is the diffrence between RETURN and RETURNING?????

Comment: Im wondering, you guys that comment this out, do you know plpgsql? If you so, why don't you give me a hint???

Comment: Assuming that the combination of the first, second, and fourth shown column are unique, it looks like the time_index_real column is redundant.  If you need it you can always calculate it.  That said, `select fn_name, count(*) + 1 from tablename where time_type = 'Start' group by fn_name` should get you started.  I'd suggest that you write a trigger first that sets the column to any value whatsoever, say 0, just so you can verify you know how to write a trigger.  Once that's working, you can worry about the logic to get the right value.

Comment: User has posted follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31018967/398670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, any changes you make to `NEW.time_index` will be ignored. The record is already inserted at this point; it's too late to modify it.

Create the trigger as `BEFORE INSERT` instead.

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried with BEFORE INSERT, open the table and manually place the values, but it shows the message... ERROR: cannot return non-composite value from function returning composite type CONTEXT: PL/pgPSQL function on_ai_mytable() line 17 at RETURN  <<<<<<<<< line 17 is... "NEW.time_index = t_ix;"

Comment: @Natysiu: Have you made any changes to the function? The version in your question seems to work perfectly. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cf997/4).

Comment: Thanks, yes it worked, I really also want to thank the guy who passed me the code, even when it had many typos, along with the AFTER placed instead of BEFORE and some others, but it gave me quite a hint of how to write the code. Unfourtunaly, we had I misunderstanding, I could not thank him, so I do it now. I don't remember its nick, the original post was deleted.