# what is "DESC LIMIT 1" used for in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

what is "DESC LIMIT 1" used for in plpgsql???
in this example

```
ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not really `DESC LIMIT 1`, the `DESC` is connected to `ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC` and `LIMIT 1` is a second clause.

The documentation will tell you, that `DESC` will cause the `ORDER` to order in descending order, and `LIMIT 1` will limit the resultset to 1 item.

In essence these clauses together mean "give me the result that has the biggest t.timestamp02 value".

Comment: Hi Sami, so you mean that I should type in the SQL... ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC AND LIMIT 1

Comment: Am I right? Also it will mean that I will get the timestamp with the highest value, the most recently one? (the last timestamp)??

Comment: @Natysiu16 No, the clause is correct without any changes. it is just two parts and the `DESC` is not connected to the `LIMIT` part but the `ORDER` part

Comment: what happen if I want to store that last timestamp into a variable, should I type... ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC AND LIMIT 1 INTO t_ix;

Comment: I have try typing... ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC AND LIMIT 1 and it gives me and error saying... syntax error at or near "AND" how should I type it??

Comment: @Natysiu16 without the and, exactly as you have it in the question

Comment: what happen if I want to store that last timestamp into a variable, should I type... ORDER BY t.timestamp02 DESC AND LIMIT 1 INTO t_ix

Comment: No, never AND in between

Comment: Hi Sami, please could you help me with this question? is also postgreSQL related, I will appreciate you alot. Thanks Advanced  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942869/insert-a-number-in-a-column-based-on-other-columns-old-inserts

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` means that the order will be *descending* (largest values first). `LIMIT 1` means only return at most one result.

So you'll get the highest `timestamp02` value.

Comment: So, what happens if Im using ORDER BY DESC LIMIT with a timestamp type of column? Will I get highest? timestamp, in other words the most recent timestamp (the last timestamp)??? Am I right?

Comment: @Natysiu16: Did you read the last sentence of the answer? Yes, the highest (most recent) value.

Comment: Thank TJ Crowder, thanks alot, could you please hep me with this question? its also postgreSQL related, I will appreciate you alot. Thanks Advanced http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942869/insert-a-number-in-a-column-based-on-other-columns-old-inserts