# unexpected end of function definition on PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

What is wrong with this function? 
EDITED>>

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_ai_myTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

BEGIN
SELECT fn_name, count(*) + 1 FROM table_ebscb_spa_log02 WHERE time_type = 'Start' GROUP BY fn_name
RETURN NEW.fn_name;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Ok I added the ";" but now, when I try to create it, it send me the message  ERROR: syntax error at or near "RETURN"
LINE 5: RETURN fn_name;

How can I solve it????

Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add semicolons:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_ai_myTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$

BEGIN
SELECT fn_name, count(*) + 1 FROM table_ebscb_spa_log02 WHERE time_type = 'Start' GROUP BY fn_name;
RETURN NEW.fn_name;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Hi user_0 could you please help me with this question? is also related to postgreSQL, I have a script  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942869/insert-a-number-in-a-column-based-on-other-columns-old-inserts

Comment: btw, please check I edited the question, something else happened. Hope I don't abuse you support, Im very grateful

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon at the end of the SELECT statement, and another semicolon following the END:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_ai_myTable() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
  BEGIN
    SELECT fn_name, count(*) + 1 FROM table_ebscb_spa_log02 WHERE time_type = 'Start' GROUP BY fn_name;
    RETURN NEW.fn_name;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See [PL/pgSQl block layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-structure.html)
And [Executing a query with a single-row result](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Also note that you will need to change the SELECT statement - the way you have it written now, the PL/pgSQL compiler will complain that it has no place to put the results (you've requested two values, fn_nam and count(*) + 1), but you are missing an INTO clause.

Comment: Thanks korry, I would like to check both answers, but user_0 posted first, thanks again man. I have another question of postgreSQL that I would like you to check, if Im not abusing of your support.